# Cygnus to Ckan: Error storing data

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, ckan, fiware-cygnus

I have Cygnus configured to store all entities coming from Orion to CKAN. When I try to store the information from the entities in http://demo.ckan.org/ organization, dataset and resource are created correctly, but data is not stored.

I have Cygnus 0.12.1-16 and Orion 0.27.0-1 installed in my environment.
I am using `attr_persistence=row` to store data.

I think the problem is when the datastore is created and when the data is stored.

When the datastore is created a field is called fiware-servicepath , but when the data is stored the field is fiwareServicePath.

Datastore creation:

```
time=2016-02-22T10:31:38.847CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[272] : >> POST /api/3/action/datastore_create HTTP/1.1
time=2016-02-22T10:31:38.847CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> Authorization: 7c426d08-f650-4a30-8577-e5281749e517
time=2016-02-22T10:31:38.847CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> Content-Length: 429
time=2016-02-22T10:31:38.847CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
time=2016-02-22T10:31:38.848CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> Host: demo.ckan.org:80
time=2016-02-22T10:31:38.848CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> Connection: Keep-Alive
time=2016-02-22T10:31:38.848CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)
time=2016-02-22T10:31:38.849CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[86] :  >> "{ "resource_id": "c34dd03e-6769-4bb7-940f-023338ff971f", "fields": [ { "id": "recvTimeTs", "type": "int"},{ "id": "recvTime", "type": "timestamp"},{ "id": "fiware-servicepath", "type": "text"},{ "id": "entityId", "type": "text"},{ "id": "entityType", "type": "text"},{ "id": "attrName", "type": "text"},{ "id": "attrType", "type": "text"},{ "id": "attrValue", "type": "json"},{ "id": "attrMd", "type": "json"}], "force": "true" }"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.143CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.143CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Server: nginx/1.1.19[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.143CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 09:31:39 GMT[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.145CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.145CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Content-Length: 534[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.146CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.146CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Vary: Accept-Encoding[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.146CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.146CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.146CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.147CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[253] : Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.147CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[256] : << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.147CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Server: nginx/1.1.19
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.147CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 09:31:39 GMT
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.147CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.147CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Content-Length: 534
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.148CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Connection: keep-alive
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.148CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Vary: Accept-Encoding
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.148CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Pragma: no-cache
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.148CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Datastore update:

```
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.610CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[272] : >> POST /api/3/action/datastore_upsert HTTP/1.1
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.610CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> Authorization: 7c426d08-f650-4a30-8577-e5281749e517
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.610CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> Content-Length: 4702
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.610CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.611CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> Host: demo.ckan.org:80
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.611CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> Connection: Keep-Alive
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.611CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=sendRequestHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[275] : >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.1 (java 1.5)
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.615CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[86] :  >> "{ "resource_id": "c34dd03e-6769-4bb7-940f-023338ff971f", "records": [ {"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responsePatient1","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "5"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responsePatient10","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "2"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responsePatient2","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "3"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responsePatient3","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "4"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responsePatient4","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "4"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responsePatient5","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "3"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responsePatient6","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "3"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responsePatient7","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "4"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responsePatient8","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "2"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responsePatient9","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "4"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responseSpecialist1","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "4"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responseSpecialist10","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "5"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responseSpecialist2","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "1"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responseSpecialist3","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "3"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responseSpecialist4","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "2"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responseSpecialist5","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "3"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responseSpecialist6","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "5"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responseSpecialist7","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "2"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responseSpecialist8","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "4"},{"recvTimeTs": "1456133486","recvTime": "2016-02-22T09:31:26.861Z","fiwareServicePath": "jsb","entityId": "User2_1_1","entityType": "User_Itinerary_Program","attrName": "responseSpecialist9","attrType": "integer","attrValue": "1"} ], "method": "insert", "force": "true" }"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.810CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.811CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Server: nginx/1.1.19[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.811CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 09:31:40 GMT[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.811CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.811CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Content-Length: 199[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.812CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.815CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.816CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.817CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[72] :  << "[\r][\n]"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.817CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[253] : Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.817CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[256] : << HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.819CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Server: nginx/1.1.19
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.819CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Date: Mon, 22 Feb 2016 09:31:40 GMT
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.820CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.820CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Content-Length: 199
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.820CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Connection: keep-alive
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.821CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Pragma: no-cache
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.821CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=receiveResponseHeader | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection[259] : << Cache-Control: no-cache
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.826CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=execute | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector[509] : Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.827CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=createJsonResponse | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpBackend[271] : Http response: HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.827CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=wire | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.Wire[86] :  << "{"help": "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_upsert", "success": false, "error": {"records": ["row \"1\" has extra keys \"fiwareServicePath\""], "__type": "Validation Error"}}"
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.827CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=releaseConnection | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager[262] : Connection [id: 1][route: {}->http://demo.ckan.org:80] can be kept alive indefinitely
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.832CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=releaseConnection | comp=Cygnus | msg=org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager[269] : Connection released: [id: 1][route: {}->http://demo.ckan.org:80][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 100; total allocated: 1 of 500]
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.832CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=createJsonResponse | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpBackend[280] : response payload: {"help": "http://demo.ckan.org/api/3/action/help_show?name=datastore_upsert", "success": false, "error": {"records": ["row \"1\" has extra keys \"fiwareServicePath\""], "__type": "Validation Error"}}
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.832CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=doRequest | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.http.HttpBackend[138] : The used Http endpoint is not active, trying another one (host=demo.ckan.org)
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.833CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=processNewBatches | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink[411] : [com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.ckan.CKANBackendImpl.insert(CKANBackendImpl.java:176), com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.ckan.CKANBackendImpl.persist(CKANBackendImpl.java:80), com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionCKANSink.persistAggregation(OrionCKANSink.java:386), com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionCKANSink.persistBatch(OrionCKANSink.java:181), com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.processNewBatches(OrionSink.java:402), com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink.process(OrionSink.java:150), org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68), org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)]
time=2016-02-22T10:31:39.833CET | lvl=ERROR | trans=1456133435-163-0000000000 | srv=jsb | subsrv=jsb | function=processNewBatches | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionSink[424] : Runtime error (Don't know how to treat response code 409)
```

Full log file: http://pastebin.com/HpVPGjhz

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. This issue has been fixed in the current develop branch:

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/800

It will appear fixed as well in the upcoming 0.13.0 version (at the moment of writting this, by the end of the week).